If $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ totally ramified, is $\mathcal{O}_K / \pi^n \mathcal{O}_K \cong \mathbb{Z} / p^n \mathbb{Z}$?
As in the title, if $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is a finite and totally ramified extension, is $\mathcal{O}_K / \pi^n \mathcal{O}_K \cong \mathbb{Z} / p^n \mathbb{Z}$ for all $n \ge 1$?
Obviously the case $n = 1$ holds since the residue fields are equal (totally ramified). Also, I believe the rings have the same order: considering the power series representations in $\mathcal{O}_K$, then truncating to length $n$, we see
$$ \# \left(\mathcal{O}_K / \pi^n \mathcal{O}_K\right) = p^n $$
However, is it isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} / p^n \mathbb{Z}$ as a ring?

When $K$ is any finite extension of $\mathbf Q_p$, $\mathcal O_K/\pi^n\mathcal O_K$ has size $p^{nf}$, where $f$ is the residue field degree.  It's worth noting that the additive group $\mathcal O_K/\pi^n\mathcal O_K$ when $n \geq 1$ could be cyclic only when $K/\mathbf Q_p$ is totally ramified:  $\mathcal O_K/\pi^n\mathcal O_K$ has subgroup $\pi^{n-1}\mathcal O_K/\pi^n\mathcal O_K \cong \mathcal O_K/\pi\mathcal O_K$, which is the additive group of the residue field and that is cyclic only when it is $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$, meaning $K/\mathbf Q_p$ is totally ramified.

True as you say for $n=1$, but for any $n \ge 2$, these are not even isomorphic as abelian groups unless the extension is trivial. Let's assume it's not, i.e. $\pi^e \mathcal{O} = p\mathcal{O}$ for some $e \ge 2$.
Now for any homomorphism of abelian groups $f: \mathbb Z/p^n \rightarrow \mathcal{O}/\pi^n$, the image is additively generated by $f(1+p^n)$. But for $n \ge 2$, the group $\mathcal{O}/\pi^n$ does not contain an additive generator -- the $\mathbb Z$-multiples of anything $\notin \pi +\pi^n$ do not contain anything that is $\equiv \pi$ mod $\pi^k$, while the $\mathbb Z$-multiples of anything in $\pi + \pi^n$ do not contain anything that is not $\equiv \pi$ mod $\pi^n$.
In fact, since in the given situation $1, \pi, ..., \pi^{e-1}$ is a $\mathbb Z_p$-basis of $\mathcal{O}$, we have e.g. $\mathcal{O}/\pi^n \simeq \mathbb F_p^{\oplus n}$ for all $n\le e$; or even more generally, if $n=ke+r$ with $k\in 0,1,2, ...$ and $0\le r \le e-1$,
$$\mathcal{O}/\pi^n \simeq (\mathbb Z/p^{k+1})^{\oplus r} \oplus (\mathbb Z/p^{k})^{\oplus e-r}.$$

When $K$ is not necessarily totally ramified, so $\mathcal O$ need not have powers of $\pi$ as a $\mathbf Z_p$-basis, the isomorphism at the end generalizes to $\mathcal O/(\pi^n) \cong (\mathbf Z/p^{k+1})^{\oplus rf} \bigoplus (\mathbf Z/p^k)^{\oplus (e-r)f}$, where $f = f(K/\mathbf Q_p)$ is the residue field degree (not to be confused with your homomorphism of abelian groups written as $f$).

@KCd: Thanks, I was thinking about including that case as well but decided against it. Now maybe OP can generalize even further to the case of an arbitrary extension $L \vert K$ of local, or at least $p$-adic, fields, as an exercise.

Or extend to a DVR $A$ contained in a Dedekind domain $B$ such that $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module: let $\mathfrak p$ be the maximal ideal in $A$, pick a maximal ideal $\mathfrak P$ in $B$, and describe $B/\mathfrak P^n$ for each $n \geq 1$ as a direct sum of cyclic $A$-modules.
